# Is it rare for two different anime to share the same OP/ED song?

Tags: anime-production, theme-song

I have watched the anime *[Ano Hi Mita Hana no Namae wo Bokutachi wa Mada Shiranai](https://myanimelist.net/anime/9989/Ano_Hi_Mita_Hana_no_Namae_wo_Bokutachi_wa_Mada_Shiranai).* It has the ED song

> "secret base ~Kimi ga Kureta Mono~ (10 years after ver.) (secret base
>   〜君がくれたもの〜（10 years after Ver.）)" by Meiko Honma (Ai Kayano), Naruko
>   Anjou (Haruka Tomatsu), Chiriko Tsurumi (Saori Hayami)

A few years later after I watched AnoHana, I watched an old anime, *[Kyou no 5 no 2](https://myanimelist.net/anime/4903/Kyou_no_5_no_2_TV)*. I heard one of its ED songs, and it's really similar to AnoHana's ED song. The title of Kyou no 5 no 2's ED song was like:

> "secret base ~Kimi ga Kureta Mono~ 「secret base ～君がくれたもの～」" by Friends:
>   Yuu Kobayashi, Asami Shimoda, MAKO, Satomi Akesaka, Youko Honda, Kana
>   Asumi

So my question: **Is it possible/rare for a song that is used in the OP/ED of an anime to be used also in the OP/ED of a different anime?**

Has this ever happened to other anime? Or is it just a coincidence?

Comment: I am no expert, but my guess would be that songs are "rented"  and/ or exclusively produced for anime. A studio probably buys the rights to use this song in their OP and ED.

Comment: Raildex is fairly correct here. OP and EDs can just be any old song, however there tends to be less of an overlap as most shows tend to opt for having custom done songs for their show, however there are examples of songs just using whatever's popular and seemingly fits the show. Shows like JoJo and Mushishi both use foreign songs they've obtained the rights to, and other shows could easily do the same, so I wouldn't put it past this having happened at some point, but I would say it certainly it is a rare occurrence for shows to share the same song.

Comment: ranma 1/2 and di gi charat nyo share one ending "equal romance" in both cases preformed by different artists

Comment: For the "secret base", the original song was released 2001 and used for live action drama "Kids war". I think both 5 no 2 (2008) and anohana (2011) just uses famous song.
The other example is [Ya Boy Kongming!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ya_Boy_Kongming!) (2022) ep is Kibun-joujou which is released in 2006 and used in TV show in that time.

Comment: After some research [Heaven's Lost Property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaven%27s_Lost_Property) uses random JPOP for each end song for each episode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very rare.

The only instance I can think of is *Elfen Lied* (2004) and *Otogizoushi* (2004).
And it's very indirect.

Both of them share the same ED Single CD which has these tracks:

1. Be your girl
2. Hoshi ni negai wo
3. Be your girl (karaoke)
4. Hoshi ni negai wo (karaoke)

"Be your girl" is the ED of *Elfen Lied*, while "Hoshi ni negai wo" is the ED of *Otogizoushi*.

Comment: damn, finally some fine answer

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen these but I read [that the ff song](https://taiko.fandom.com/wiki/Asu_e_no_Tobira)

> "Asu e no Tobira" (Japanese: 明日への扉, Asu e no Tobira) is a song performed by the pop group I Wish.

is used in

1 - [Teasing Master Takagi-san: The Movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teasing_Master_Takagi-san:_The_Movie)

> Ending theme music
>
> In June 2022, it was revealed that the film's ending theme music would change weekly for four weeks, beginning with Rie Takahashi performing "The Door to Tomorrow" (明日への扉, Asu e no Tobira) by I Wish on the first week of its release.

2 - [ReLIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReLIFE) S01E10

> 10    "Asu e no Tobira" (明日への扉)   I Wish

3 - [Kase-san](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kase-san)

> The main theme is a cover of I WiSH's 2003 song "Asu e no Tobira" (明日への扉, Door Towards Tomorrow), performed by Minami Takahashi and Ayane Sakura.